# Как хранятся строки в golang?

Tags: строки, golang, указатели, байты

Создаю несколько переменных подряд.
Далее к одной переменной прибавляю произвольные данные и вижу что она осталась по своему же адресу.

```
package main

func main() {

    i := 5
    println(&i)
    st := "st"
    println("st", &st)
    j := "jj"
    println("j", &j)
    st = "ssffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff " + st
    println("st", &st)

}


0xc00003c748
st 0xc00003c750
j 0xc00003c760
st 0xc00003c750
```

Я ожидал что при конкатенации она перенесется в другое место и будет новый адрес.
Т.е. поидеи итоговая строка "st" вобще не должна уместиться в промежуток между
0xc00003c760 и 0xc00003c748 там всего 12 байт получается

Comment: Строка — это переменная, состоящая из двух полей: длины и указателя на содержимое (на 64-битных системах эта переменная обычно занимает 16 байт — по 8 байт на каждое поле). Меняя строку, вы меняете эти два поля, но сама переменная в целом остаётся там же, где изначально и была. Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720693) и [тут](https://research.swtch.com/godata)

Comment: Понятно, спасибо

Comment: FYI, представление строк в памяти и реализация низкоуровневых операций со строками приведена в файле [`src/runtime/string.go`](https://go.dev/src/runtime/string.go#L238)

Answer (score 1):

1. Строка -- это замаскированный срез байтов. Ссылка на срез байтов -- та же самая. Указатель на срез байтов -- другой. И вы можете получить указатель на ссылку. Но не указатель на указатель на срез байтов.
2. Получать указатель от ссылки на строку (она берётся автоматически) -- бессмысленно, так как строки при вызовах автоматически передаются по ссылке.